# Choosing Blackberry Development Envinronment - Issues

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-eclipse-plugin, blackberry-jde

I need help with some confusing terms in blackberry development world. As you can see, I am newbie to bb dev and the myriad of available tools and installtions is just too much to comprehend.

From reading several forums and articles, I have decided to go with Blackberry Java Plug-in for Eclipse. I understand that this is different from using Blackberry JDE. So I went through the set up as described in the "[BlackBerry Java Plug-in for Eclipse](http://us.blackberry.com/developers/javaappdev/javaplugin.jsp)" page, and started creating BlackBerry projects. When I tried to find some more details about how to make project changed, like the App Icon or including image resources, I find that Eclipse doesn't have certain options so I am wondering if I am missing something. For example:

To add a image resource to the project: I added the file to the project path and refreshed my project in Eclipse to view the new file. I can't find "Blackberry Project Properties" in the menu. I can't find the menu item Configure Blackberry Workspace under "Blackberry" menu.

Upon research, I find this article "[BlackBerry JDE Plug-in for Eclipse](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/4240/BlackBerry_JDE_Plug-in_for_Eclipse_Help.pdf)"  which talks about a Blackberry "JDE" Plug-in For Eclipse. Now is this different or same as the one I am using?

Do I need the Blackberry JDE Component Package if I am not using Blackberry JDE and if I am using only the Blackberry Java Plug-in for Eclipse?

Any help is much appreciated.

Eclipse Helios V 3.6
Blackberry Java Plugin for Eclipse v 1.3.0

Comment: What version of Eclipse are you using?

Comment: edited my question with the version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your BlackBerry project, what jdk is selected?   If you have the BlackBerry plugin setup correctly, you should be able to select a BlackBerry JRE, and you should see the BlackBerry logo in a few places.  On the project folder icon, you can see the blackberry logo above the folder.      On the BlackBerry_App_Descriptor.xml file, you can also see the BlackBerry logo.
Then, on the JRE System Library line, you can see that there is a special JRE.

When I am checking my Eclipse setup, I visually scan for those BlackBerry logos, and that tells me the plugin is setup.   The final check is that the right JRE is selected.   The key is that 'BlackBerry' needs to appear between those brackets in the JRE name.

[image: Package Explorer screenshot]

When you double-click on the BlackBerry_App_Descriptor.xml file, you should be presented with an editor screen that looks like this:
[image]

Comment: I go to Help -> Blackberry Java Plug-in for Eclipse and I see the version information and I can see the installation details. I used the Help - Install Software tool to install multiple Blackberry Java SDKs starting from 4.5 through 6.0. In Run Configurations - I am able to select the JREs.

Comment: So may be I have this set up correctly. But the problem is I can't use any image files in the res folder. Is this a known issue? Some documents I find online mention that When I click Clackberry_App_Descriptor.xml - I should see a Blackberry Configuration - option which I don't see. All I see is "Resource" and "Run/Debug Settings".

Comment: @Dave You should be able to add an icon in the "Application Icons" section.  I've included a screenshot in my answer above.

Comment: Thanks Michael. Sorry for the delay in accepting your answer. I was able to include images directly under the project folder (not in res) and then access it in code. Adding images through the blackberry app descriptor file works the same. I am having to put in the files in the root dir.